# Run a CRON job that depends on entries of a database in NodeJS using AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

I want to make schedules that depend on  entries of a database to schedule cron jobs. Like if there's an entry in database with a timestamp 2:00 PM, 3rd of Apr, I want to send a mail to users on 2nd of Apr. I also want to send notifications at 1:55 PM 3rd of Apr.

So, this means I have to look into the database, find the entries after the current times tamp, see if they suit the criteria for notification (like 5 minutes to time stamp or 1 day to time stamp) and send the notification or mail. I'm only worried that **every one minute** seems like too much overload. Are the AWS web workers built for this sort of thing?

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think crontab will be the best choice but if you're familiar with it, it's fine.

First you should estimate how frequently your entries are created. If, let's say, only a couple of hundred a day. My suggestion is to create the crontab job right after the entry is created. But if more than a hundred a minutes, pooling will be fine.

But there are also side effects, like canceling or updating the cron job .

I think it's better to use a proper MQ.

Comment: Oh. I have way less. One entry per day. That's what worries me. Check every minute for one per day. I don't know when that will happen but it's one per day at max.

Comment: So it's totally fine just to create a cron job every time you insert the entry.